# How to write Docker file and compose for rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, sqlite, docker, docker-compose

i'm newbie to Docker. I have a web app which is written in react js. It contains rails(sqlite3) server to store the data. I have file structure as follows:

```
  Project:
    1.Front end: dockerfile1, .dockerignore1
    2.Back end: docker file2 , .dockerignore2
    3.Dockercompose.yml
```

dockerfile1:

```
 # Stage 1
 FROM node:8 as react-build
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY . ./
 RUN yarn
 RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

.dockerignore1

```
.git
 node_modules
 build
```

Then I have created the container1:  $ docker build . -t container1
When i run '$ docker run -p 8000:80 container1' & when i give 'http://localhost:8000' on browser , it displays front end page.

I don't know how to write the dockerfile2 for rails server which has sqlite3 database. Then I should write docker compose file.Someone please help me to write docker compose file for communicate between web app and rails server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

follow these instruction by docker :

https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

also to know structure check below link:

https://github.com/adaam2/docker-rails-react-starter